# Enupal Snapshot: Fail to save setting for Craft Nitro with status code '127'

Tags: assets, pdf, nitro, windows, plugin-enupalpdf

I keep having issues when trying to save the settings for Enupal Snapshot at Craft Nitro,
[image]

Below is the error message I found at the log file,

```
[enupal\snapshot\Snapshot::error] Something went wrong when creating the PDF file: The exit status code '127' says something went wrong:
stderr: "sh: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: not found

[error][enupal\snapshot\Snapshot::error] Something went wrong when creating the Image file: The exit status code '127' says something went wrong:
stderr: "sh: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage: not found
```

I have installed the wkhtmltopdf at Ubuntu 20.04 based on the [documentation](https://docs.enupal.com/enupal-snapshot/getting-started/installation-setup.html#install-wkhtmltopdf-on-ubuntu-via-command-line) and get the path using 'which wkhtmltopdf', 'which wkhtmltoimage'
[image]

I have also enabled the Public URL for the asset,
[image]

How can I fix this?

I'm using Nitro 2 at Window 10 x64, below are my system details,

```
Ubuntu 20
PHP version 7.4.16
OS version  Linux 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Craft Pro 3.6.13
Enupal Snapshot 1.2.8
```

Comment: I'll try to install snapshot on nitro2. I'll back to you soon

Comment: @AndreL. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because **wkhtmltopdf** wasn't installed on the right server. I need to install the package inside the nitro server by ssh into the root of the container.

Here is the steps,

```
nitro ssh --root 
apk add  --no-cache --repository  http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main/ wkhtmltopdf=0.12.6-r0
```

**wkhtmltopdf=0.12.6-r0** is the version.

You might need to update your package if you fail to install,

```
apk update
```

After your installation, you should be able to get the path,

```
which wkhtmltopdf 
which wkhtmltoimage
```

In case you want to check your version, you can run the below command after getting your path,

```
/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --version
```

Here is the reference,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59026248/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-on-docker-ruby-2-5-1-alpine-linux

Comment: Keep in mind that this will get blown away if you ever update the container

Answer (score 1):

Was the value you got from which whtmlopdf $whtmlopdf? Return code 127 is

> Value 127 is returned by /bin/sh when the given command is not found within your PATH system variable and it is not a built-in shell command. In other words, the system doesn't understand your command, because it doesn't know where to find the binary you're trying to call.
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from

So I'm thinking it has something to do with that. I had a few issues getting it setup so am happy to try and help.

Comment: Basically the system not able to detect the path for whtmlopdf, which I have installed

Answer (score 1):

To install Enupal Snapshot on Nitro 2 (could be the same for Alpine Linux distros)

- Login to nitro via ssh as root:
  `nitro ssh your_nitro_site_name --root`
- Run the following command to install `wkhtmltopdf` and dependencies

```
apk --update --no-cache add \
   wkhtmltopdf \
    libgcc \
    libstdc++ \
    musl \
    qt5-qtbase \
    qt5-qtbase-x11 \
    qt5-qtsvg \
    qt5-qtwebkit \
    ttf-freefont \
    ttf-dejavu \
    ttf-droid \
    ttf-liberation \
    fontconfig \
    so:libQt5Core.so.5 \
    so:libQt5Gui.so.5 \
    so:libQt5Network.so.5 \
    so:libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 \
    so:libQt5Svg.so.5 \
    so:libQt5WebKit.so.5\
    so:libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5\
    so:libQt5Widgets.so.5\
    so:libc.musl-x86_64.so.1\
    so:libgcc_s.so.1\
    so:libstdc++.so.6
```

- On your Craft CMS dashboard go to the Enupal Snapshot settings and save the following settings:

Absolute Binary Path of wkhtmltopdf libRequired:
`/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

Absolute Binary Path of wkhtmltoimage lib
`/usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage`

- Save your Settings

This was an issue raised on Github -> [#43](https://github.com/enupal/snapshot/issues/43)